# Long Internet operations with limited bandwidth

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

yesterday I published my application which I tested on my phone and worked as intended. When my friends downloaded it using 3G and not WiFi my application failed to download all the content and as a result it crashed. I used a headless fragment which runs an AsyncTask in order to download the content (which is some photos) my guess is that it took a lot of time for some photos  and skipped them, throwing some timeOut exception. My question is would this be avoided if instead of an fragment I used a service to run my AsyncTask and download the content?

```
  private ArrayList<Monument> processJsonData(JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException{

  try{                  



    JSONArray posts=jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
    ArrayList<Monument> monuments = new ArrayList<Monument>();

    for (int i=0; i<posts.length(); i++){



            JSONArray attachments = c.optJSONArray(TAG_ATTACHMENTS);
            if(attachments!=null){
                int lengthSize;
                if(attachments.length()<3)
                    lengthSize=attachments.length();
                else
                    lengthSize=3;
                for(int j=0;j<lengthSize;++j){                              

                            JSONObject atta = attachments.getJSONObject(j); 
                            JSONObject images = atta.optJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES); 
                            if(images!=null){
                                JSONObject medium = images.getJSONObject(TAG_MEDIUM);
                                String url_image = medium.getString(TAG_URL_IMAGE);                                 
                                String  id = atta.getString("id");

                                String filename =title.replace(" ","")+id+".nomedia";
                                File destination = new File(MyApplication.getPhotoStorage() ,filename);

                                URL url = new URL (url_image);

                                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);


                                byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                                int length;

                                while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                                    os.write(b, 0, length);
                                }

                                is.close();
                                os.close();
                                localPhotosUrl.add(destination.getAbsolutePath());
                            }


               }
        }




    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
   return null;

  }
```

**Edit** so I made these changes in my code now I'm dealing with the connectionTimeout exception but I can't catch it properly

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {               


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    Log.d("check1",url);
    try {

        listOfObjects.addAll(processJsonData(jsonObj));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            onDownloadFailed(this);
        } finally {
            jsonObj=null;
        }


        return "done"; 
    }
```

---

```
        protected void onDownloadFailed(downloadUrl task) {

        System.out.println(task.tag+" failed to download");
        if(dtask1.cancel(true))
            Log.d("TASK1", "Canceled");
        if(dtask2.cancel(true))
            Log.d("TASK2", "Canceled");
        if(dtask3.cancel(true))
            Log.d("TASK3", "Canceled");
        if(dtask4.cancel(true))
            Log.d("TASK4", "Canceled");

        mCallbacks.onDownloadFailed();

    }



  private ArrayList<Monument> processJsonData(JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException, SocketException, JSONException{

            JSONArray attachments = c.optJSONArray(TAG_ATTACHMENTS);
            if(attachments!=null){
                int lengthSize;
                if(attachments.length()<3)
                    lengthSize=attachments.length();
                else
                    lengthSize=3;

                for(int j=0;j<lengthSize;++j){                              

                            JSONObject atta = attachments.getJSONObject(j); 
                            JSONObject images = atta.optJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES); 
                            if(images!=null){
                                JSONObject medium = images.getJSONObject(TAG_MEDIUM);
                                String url_image = medium.getString(TAG_URL_IMAGE);                                 
                                String  id = atta.getString("id");

                                String filename =title.replace(" ","")+id+".nomedia";
                                File destination = new File(MyApplication.getPhotoStorage() ,filename);

                                try{
                                    URL url = new URL (url_image);

                                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);


                                    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                                    int length;

                                    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                                        os.write(b, 0, length);
                                    }

                                    is.close();
                                    os.close();
                                    localPhotosUrl.add(destination.getAbsolutePath());

                                }catch (SocketException e) {
                                    throw new SocketTimeoutException();
                                }



                            }


               }
        }
```

Comment: We're likely to need to see an example of your issue in code, as well as more details on your problem in order to give you a good answer.

Comment: ok I'll edit it adding some code, I just described it in an abstract in order to be more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I don't know much about JSON, but that shouldn't affect this answer as a whole I don't think. It looks like your issue could be solved by [better use of `Exception` handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm).

At the moment you are not really handling the exception at all, merely catching it and printing the stack trace. Also, because the entire method is inside one `try{ }` statement the method is exiting if there is a problem dealing with any one of the attachments. Instead, you could include a `try{ }` block inside of your `for` loop. This way, if any one of the loop blocks failed (due to say an unstable connection), you can use the catch block to `j--;` and then `Thread.sleep(4000);`. That way, when an exception is thrown in the loop it will be caught, the loop will be jumped back to try the same section again, and there will be a pause to to wait for a better connection.

Example (Not tested);

```
for (int j = 0; j < lengthSize; ++j) {

    try{
        JSONObject atta = attachments.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONObject images = atta.optJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES);
        if (images != null) {
            JSONObject medium = images.getJSONObject(TAG_MEDIUM);
            String url_image = medium.getString(TAG_URL_IMAGE);
            String id = atta.getString("id");

            String filename = title.replace(" ", "") + id + ".nomedia";
            File destination = new File(MyApplication.getPhotoStorage(), filename);

            URL url = new URL(url_image);

            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);


            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
            localPhotosUrl.add(destination.getAbsolutePath());
        } 
    }catch (Exception e){
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         j--;
    }
}
```

You may also want to create a counter to see how many attempts have been made. If the code makes too many attempts you can then assume that it will never work and return from the method.

I hope this helps. Let me know how you get on.

---

Also, as an aside you should never really catch `Exception`. Better to catch the specific exception/s you are expecting so that you can deal with them differently depending on the `Exception` subtype. You don't want to catch a `RunTimeException` and try to handle it when there may be no effective way of doing so.

Comment: I've just seen your answer. I made some changes in my code yesterday, but still got some questions I'll edit it in a while

Comment: @libathos - I've just had a read of your edit. What kind of trouble are you having in catching it? What is and isn't happening? What kind of behavior do you expect?

Comment: In the logcan I get the SocketTimeout exception in yellow, if I caught the exception it shouldn't be print at all, correct?

Comment: @libathos - Ah, okay. No, it should still print in the log because your calling `e.printStackTrace();` in `doInBackground()`. Also, your catching `SocketException` and throwing a `SocketTimeoutException`, even though `SocketTimeoutException` isn't a subtype of `SocketException`. Better to just `throw e;` for ease of reading's sake.

Answer (score 0):

No. This won't be avoided. You cannot expect a connection to last for a long time. Anything can happen on the phone (battery exhausted, network signal lost, etc.)

You must code your app so that it properly checks if it has all the resources available and to retry (or better, resume) downloads that failed.

To increase your chances, break your resources in relatively small downloads instead of a huge file. Then the user does not have to download all from scratch when using 3G for instance.

Comment: I see your point but, each time the content is different so I cannot know it beforehand, I think I should get the connectionTimedOut exception and display a message to the user.